# How can i use custom function to validate post data in php

Tags: php

I want to validate my form post using  function and then insert it into database.
I have been able to do that without putting it into function but when i put it into a function it inserts without validating the input fields.
Thanks ;)
Here is my code:

```
  <?php
      function validate_post(){
          global $link;

          if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {           
              $error = array();

              if (!isset($_POST['cat_title']) || empty($_POST['cat_title'])) {
                  $error[] = "field cannot be empty";
              } else {
                  //check if a name only contains letters and whitespace
                  if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $_POST['cat_title'])) {
                      $cat_err = "Only letters and whitespace allowed";
                  }
              }
              //if no errors found
              if (empty($error) && empty($cat_err)) {
                  $cat_title = htmlentities($_POST['cat_title']);
                  $sql = "INSERT INTO categories(cat_title)VALUES('$cat_title')";
                  $insert = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
                  confirm_query($insert);
                  if (mysqli_affected_rows($link) == 1) {
                      $post_info = "Category has been added";
                      redirect("categories.php");
                  } else {
                      $post_info = "Adding category failed";
                  }
              } else {
                  $post_info = "Field cannot be empty";
              }
          }    
      }
  ?>

<?php validate_post(); ?><!-- call validate_post function-->
<!-- ADD CATEGORY FORM -->
<form action="" method="post">
<?php  
    if(isset($post_info))echo $post_info."<br>";
    if(isset($cat_err))echo $cat_err."\n" ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cat_tile">Categories</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cat_title" id="cat_tile"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="+ Add Category" name="submit" >
     </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: data doesn't get posted to the function, you need to pass the data from `$_POST` to the function by reference e.g. `function foo($bar) { if(isset($bar)) {}}`

Comment: pass the post data to function as matt says

Comment: `$_POST` is a global variable you don't need to pass it into the function to use it within the functiuon.

Comment: @Matt you mean function validate_post($cat_title) { if(isset($cat_title)) {}}   validate_post(("cat_title")

Comment: @bgreatfit foo and bar are just examples :) and most people use foo and bar as examples for any situation.

Comment: Is the problem that the database record ACTUALLY gets inserted, or is it just that you don't see the error messages?  In your code, the $post_info and $cat_err variables that you set are both local to the function, so they will ALWAYS be unset when you do the check at the top of the form.

Comment: I tried writing a suitable answer for this question, but it cannot be done the way it is written. My answer would've been a complete rewrite of the original.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

below code will help you ..

```
<?php
    function validate_post(){
        global $link;

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $cat_err = "";
            if (!isset($_POST['cat_title']) || empty($_POST['cat_title']) || $_POST['cat_title']=="") {
                $cat_err = "field cannot be empty";
            } else {
                //check if a name only contains letters and whitespace
                if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $_POST['cat_title'])) {

                    $cat_err = "Only letters and whitespace allowed";
                }

            }

            //if no errors found
            if ($cat_err=="") {
                $cat_title = htmlentities($_POST['cat_title']);
                  $sql = "INSERT INTO categories(cat_title)VALUES('$cat_title')";
                  $insert = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
                  confirm_query($insert);
                  if (mysqli_affected_rows($link) == 1) {
                      $cat_err = "Category has been added";
                      redirect("categories.php");
                  } else {
                      $cat_err = "Adding category failed";
                  }

            } else {
                $cat_err = "Field cannot be empty";
            }
            return $cat_err;
        }
    }
    ?>
    <?php $data=validate_post();echo $data;?><!-- call validate_post function-->
    <!-- ADD CATEGORY FORM -->
    <form action="" method="post">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cat_tile">Categories</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cat_title" id="cat_tile"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="+ Add Category" name="submit" >
        </div>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your post data by reference to a function like this:

```
function checkFormValue(&$inputData) {  
    if (isset($inputData) && !empty($inputData)) {
        return $inputData;
    }
    
    return "";
}
```

Call this function on `$_POST` data to validate it:

```
$catTitle = checkFormValue($_POST["cat_title"]);
var_dump($catTitle);
```

If it fails to validate than it will return empty string. Using this function you can check `isset` and for `!empty` many of your form fields.

Answer (score -1):

Your function doesn't return any information.  You need to tell it to return the errors, and then do something with them. You need to restructure the way messages are organized in your function, but the gist is this:

add `return $error;` to the end of your validate function.

Then in your page body:

```
<?php $errors = validate_post(); ?><!-- call validate_post function-->
<!-- ADD CATEGORY FORM -->
<form action="" method="post">
   <?php  
   foreach($errors as $error)
   {
     echo $error;
   }
   ?>
    <div class="form-group">
```

So, change your validate function to save all messages into a single array, return the array, then process the items.

Variables declared inside a function only "exist" within the scope of that function. `$post_info` inside your function has no relationship to `$post_info` outside the function.

Comment: *edit* - the comment this responded to mysteriously was deleted... * He declared `$error` as an array in his function.   The way i defined `$errors = validate_post();` is not incorrect.  It can be named anything...  variables outside the scope of the function have no relationship to variables inside the scope of a function.

Answer (score -2):

Try to pass in the $_POST array:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    validate_post($_POST)
}

function validate_post($post_array) {
  // your code here
}
```

Matt first suggested this, but here is how you would do that.

Answer (score -2):

Using your code this is the rundown to what you need to do for the function.

```
<?php
function validate_post($link, $data=[]) {        
    $error = array();

    if (!isset($data['cat_title']) || empty($data['cat_title'])) {
        $error[] = "field cannot be empty";
    } else {
        //check if a name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $data['cat_title'])) {
            $cat_err = "Only letters and whitespace allowed";
        }
    }
    //if no errors found
    if (empty($error) && empty($cat_err)) {
        $cat_title = htmlentities($data['cat_title']);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO categories(cat_title)VALUES('$cat_title')";
        $insert = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        confirm_query($insert); //This is another function you created???
        if (mysqli_affected_rows($link) == 1) {
            $post_info = "Category has been added";
            redirect("categories.php");
        } else {
            $post_info = "Adding category failed";
        }
    } else {
        $post_info = "Field cannot be empty";
    }   
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    include 'dbfile.php'; // Containing your db link variable if that is how you've done it
    validate_post($link, $_POST); // Usually you need to pass your database link by reference also rather than by global.
}

?>

--html section--
```